# Consider the p-adic field $ \ \mathbb{Q}_p \ $ . Define $ \operatorname{ord}_p(x) \ $ to be the p-adic valuation of $ \ x \ $

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

Consider the p-adic field $ \ \mathbb{Q}_p \ $ . Define $ \operatorname{ord}_p(x) \ $ to be the $p$-adic valuation of $ \ x \ $  by $ \operatorname{ord}_p(x)=\max \{r : \ p^r \ \text{ divides } \ x \} \ $.

The inequality $$ 1 \leq p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n)} \leq n $$ **holds good** for every $ \ n \ $.

**My question is** -

Does the inequality $ \ 1 \leq p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(\large n^3)} \leq n \ $    holds?

That is ,  we are replacing $ \ n^3 \ $ by $ \ n \ $.

**Answer:**

Let $\ \ n=p^r \cdot \frac{a}{b} , \ b \neq 0 , \ p \ \text{ does   not  divide}\ a,b \ $

Then

$ \operatorname{ord}_p(n)=r \ $

So,

$ n^3=(p^r \cdot \frac{a}{b}) (p^r \cdot \frac{a}{b} ) (p^r \cdot \frac{a}{b}) =p^{3r} \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^3 \ $

Thus,

$ ord_p(n^3)=3r \ $

So we have,

$ 1 \leq p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n)} \leq p^{\operatorname{ord}_p(n^3)} \leq n \ $

**Am I right?**

**Please kindly check my work and correct it if necessary . Thanks.**

Comment: In your example with $n=p^r \cdot \frac{a}{b},\,b\ne 0 $, it should be $\text{ord}_p(n)=r$, not $\text{ord}_p(n)={\large{\frac{1}{p^r}}}$.

Comment: Oh yes. thanks. But can you conclude about the question?

Comment: I don't understand something here. Wouldn't increasing $b$ decrease $n$ but leave $ord_p(n)$ unchanged? So how could the inequality be true?

Comment: the first inequality is true. My question is whether the 2nd inequality is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, for the question at hand, $n$ is required to be a positive integer.

But even with that restriction, the inequality $p^{\text{ord}_p(n^3)}\le n$ is not always true.

For example, if $p$ is prime, and $n=p$, we get
$$p^{\text{ord}_p(n^3)}=p^{\text{ord}_p(p^3)}=p^3 > p = n$$

Comment: so what would be the correct inequality? Can you help little or can you predict an inequality which i written?

Comment: Can you give any similar inequality for the case $ \ ord_p(n^3) \ $  ?

Comment: For $p$ prime, and $n$ a positive integer, you can say
$$p^{\text{ord}_p(n^3)}\le n^3$$
but you already knew that.